# Referencing vanilla js file in TypeScript getting file is not a module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm trying to import a file into TypeScript that's basically just a js file that you'd put into a  tag. I've tried a few different things.

```
// global.d.ts
declare module 'myfile.js'
```

Inside of the react file:

```
// component.tsx
import { foo } from '../lib/myFile.js' // This is saying it is not a module
```

Inside of the js file, it looks like this a few times so not sure how I need to reference the file:

```
(function( something ) {
    something.Foo = function (){}
}(window.something = window.something || {}));
```

Any thoughts on how I could use this file? Do I need to go through and declare typings for everything in it?

EDIT: I've added allowJS to my tsconfig but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you actually exporting foo from your js file?

Comment: No, the file has no exports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only import what is exported from the file.

If your file contains only immediately invoked functions, or top level code, you only need to import the file itself like this:

```
import '../lib/myFile.js'
```

This is a little weird, however. I would suggest wrapping everything with a function and exporting then importing that function instead.